# Integer not incrementing in VB

Tags: vb.net, if-statement, counter

I have the following code that when the user clicks on the button the first time it does the if, then the second time it does the else. Except it is not incrementing and doing the else.

I have tried

count = count + 1

count = 1

count += 1

My code is below

```
 'new button calls second survey page and sets mode to data
    Private Sub btnTurn_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnTurn.Click
        Dim count As Integer
        If count = 0 Then
            frmSurvey2.szCaller = "frmSurvey"
            frmSurvey2.szMode = "data"
            frmSurvey2.Show()
            count += 1
        Else
            frmSurvey2.szCaller = "frmSurvey"
            frmSurvey2.szMode = "print"
            frmSurvey2.Show()
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Aside ; you should maybe use a `Boolean` instead of a counter which will go only to 1 and the common code between the if and the else (so always done) should be outside the `If` block to avoid duplication

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use vb.net's `Static` if you want to maintain your variable's lexical scope.

```
Private Sub btnTurn_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnTurn.Click
    Static count As Integer = 0
    If count = 0 Then
        ' do whatever
        count += 1
    Else
        ' do whatever else
    End If
End Sub
```

In turn, you could have another `count` in another handler which will not collide with the first one.

```
Private Sub btnOther_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnOther.Click
    Static count As Integer = 0
    If count = 0 Then
        ' do whatever
        count += 1
    Else
        ' do whatever else
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

You have a separate variable every time you call the function.
Therefore, it's always zero.

You need to declare that in your class.

Comment: Wow.. How did I forget that. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

As others have stated, each time the button click procedure is called the count is reset to zero (2nd line of code after the comment).
When you Dim a variable, it automatically sets the variable to 0 or Nothing.

To solve this, you may try to declare the count outside the button click procedure as a global variable.

Edit: you cannot use Byref and Byval here.

Thank you Verdolino for pointing that out.

I hope my answer helps!

Comment: With this button click event handler `Private Sub btnTurn_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnTurn.Click`, ByRef/ByVal is not applicable. SLaks went over class-level variable declaration

Comment: Oh yes, I completely forgot, thank you for that @Verdolino